# How to center elements relative to other elements but all fitting within an ancestor using CSS?

Tags: css

I see how to use absolute positioning to center an element below its parent, shown in the snippet example below.

But how might I "nudge" such an element so that it fits within an arbitrary ancestor container?  It should be as close to centered under its parent as possbile, but it must not "leak" outside the ancestor container element.  Is there a way to use absolute positioning to do this, or perhaps some other technique, without knowing the number of pixels (e.g. no `left: -10px;` for p1 nor `right: -20px` for p3)...that is, I want it to work no matter where the p1/p2/p3 elements happen to end up inside the container.

```css
div { border: 1px solid grey; }
.container {  text-align: center; }

.p1, .p2, .p3 {
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-inline: auto;
}  
.p1 {
  margin-left: 10px; /* could be anything*/
}
.p2 {}
.p3 {
  margin-right: 20px; /* could be anything*/
}
.message {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* naive attempt: centered under parent */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  ancestor container
  <div class=" p1">
    p1
    <div class="message">I want this centered under p1 but nudged right to ensure it fits in container</div>
  </div>
  <div class="p2">
    p2
    <div class="message">I want this centered under p2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="p3">
    p3
    <div class="message">I want this centered under p3 but nudged left to ensure it fits in container</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you need javascript for this. CSS can't *detect* the position of an element in relation to the container.

Comment: I would rethink the way of centering the element. You have no luck with position:absolute but if you consider something else you may have a chance

Answer (score -2):

Can you please post a jsfiddle so we can update your code?

Else try adding extra class like this:

```
<div class="message message1">
```

and then in css

```
.message.message1  {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use "copy snippet to answer".  SO wants us to use built-in snippets rather than third-party fiddles.

I don't want `left:0;` I want the message div to extend to the outside as much as it can till it is centered, but always stay inside the container div.

Comment: sry im not used to the copy snippet thingy... you know the margins, you can use left: -10px for the first message box. Another approach is to wrapp the p tag and the message in another div with position absolute and max-width: 100%; .. making the ancestor positioned relative.

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer that without knowing the number of pixels (e.g. no left: -10px; for p1 nor right: -20px for p3)...that is, I want it to work no matter where the p1/p2/p3 elements happen to end up inside the container.

Comment: @Patrick Szalapski
something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ymdpL9o2/39/
title you can probably set outside message and relative... play around with it :)

Comment: here is better: https://jsfiddle.net/ymdpL9o2/75/

Comment: Thanks, but again, I'm looking for a solution for when I don't know horizontally where in the page the element sits.